# No-downtime Laravel deployment

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I want to deploy a Laravel app from Gitlab to a server with no downtime. On the server, I serve the app with `php artisan serve`. Currently, I'm thinking that I would first copy all the files, then stop the old `php artisan serve` process on the server and start a new one on the server in the directory with the new files. However, this introduces a small downtime. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serving with a single server, you can not achieve 0 downtime. If downtime is a crucial part of your system, then use two server and load balance between them smartly. Remember, no hosting or VPS provider ensure you to deliver 100% availability. So if you want to get 100% availability in the deployment process, in an irony situation, your site may have been down in another time. What I'm saying is that, if tiny moment of restarting `php artisan serve` is matter, then scale up to more than one server.
A workaround solution would be use some 3rd party service (like CloudFlare) which can smartly detect server down situation and notify user when it is back, I personally use that. 
If you really want full uptime, docker with kubernetes is your technology.